# Jquery-Formulate json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have to form a json output using jquery.
What needs to be represented with this json message is a collection of items named 'bucket'. The collection will include image elements, link elements, term elements or video elements. How many items will exist in each category of elements is not pre-specified, but rather dynamic. Before proceeding with jquery I decided the json output to look like the following without being sure that this is correct.

```
{ 
    "bucket": {
        "terms": [ {
            "text": "logo design",
            "data": "Interview with Petter Johansson at Stockholm Design Week"
        } ],
        "images": [{
            "title": "Tattoo Design",
            "thumbnail": "http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.608019252933102717&pid=15.1",
            "url": "http://www.deerydesign.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Tattoo-Design-006.jpg"
        }],
        "links": [{
            "title": "Design News � Official Site",
            "link": "http://www.designnews.com/",
            "snippet": "Design News is the leading technical resource for design engineers and engineering managers who build products and systems through application of electronics & test ... "
        }],
        "videos": [{
            "title": "Design Projects done in less than a minute each ",
            "thumbnail": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vwtOGBxtI10/mqdefault.jpg",
            "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwtOGBxtI10"
        }]
    }
}
```

After that I need to form json message through jquery, but I find difficulty in doing so because of the multiple levels and the non-fixed number of items in each element's array. I started somehow like this, but I don't know how to proceed with next level.

```
jsonObj = {
        bucket: []
    };
jsonObj.bucket.push({
            "terms" : $(data).text()
        });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonObj.bucket` is an object, not an array, so you can't call `push` on it. The array is in `terms`, so it should be:

```
jsonObj = {
    bucket: {
        terms: [],
        images: [],
        links: [],
        videos: []
    }
}
```

Then you add to it with something like this (I'm just making up expressions for where the data comes from, since you haven't given enough information for me to know it):

```
jsonObj.bucket.terms.push({
    text: $(somefield).text(),
    data: $(otherfield).val()
});
```